# Sum Non Null Values Block in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add Non `Null` Values block by block without any grouping criteria :

Example input :

```
Machine  Value    DateTime
a        null     1 Dec 2021 8:34AM
a        2        1 Dec 2021 8:35AM
a        1        1 Dec 2021 9:34AM
a        3        1 Dec 2021 10:11AM
a        null     1 Dec 2021 11:14AM
a        null     1 Dec 2021 11:16AM
a        5        1 Dec 2021 11:58AM
a        6        1 Dec 2021 11:59AM
```

Example output :

```
Machine  Value    DateTime              SumValue
a        null     1 Dec 2021 8:34AM     
a        2        1 Dec 2021 8:35AM
a        1        1 Dec 2021 9:34AM
a        3        1 Dec 2021 10:11AM     6
a        null     1 Dec 2021 11:14AM
a        null     1 Dec 2021 11:16AM
a        5        1 Dec 2021 11:58AM
a        6        1 Dec 2021 11:59AM     11
```

I don't have any other grouping criteria other than device column , but I want sum block wise

Comment: What is the order of the rows?

Comment: In SQL, tables and data sets are explicitly considered unordered. This can only be solved if you add another column which the order can be derived from (such as in an ORDER BY).

Comment: Yes I have added datetime column please check and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the groups and use windowed `SUM()`:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:01', 'a', null),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:02', 'a', 2),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:03', 'a', 1),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:04', 'a', 3),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:05', 'a', null),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:06', 'a', null),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:07', 'a', 5),
   ('2021-12-12T09:00:08', 'a', 6)
) v (Date, Machine, Value)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Date, Machine, Value, 
   CASE 
      WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Machine, GroupNumber ORDER BY Date DESC) = 1 
      THEN SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Machine, GroupNumber ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
   END AS SumValue
FROM (
   SELECT
      *,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Machine ORDER BY Date) AS GroupNumber
   FROM Data
) t
ORDER BY Machine, Date
```

Result:

```
Date                Machine Value SumValue
2021-12-12T09:00:01 a       
2021-12-12T09:00:02 a       2   
2021-12-12T09:00:03 a       1   
2021-12-12T09:00:04 a       3     6
2021-12-12T09:00:05 a       
2021-12-12T09:00:06 a       
2021-12-12T09:00:07 a       5   
2021-12-12T09:00:08 a       6     11
```